# How does the C == operator decide whether or not two floating point values are equal?

Tags: c, comparison, floating-point, equality, ieee-754

Today I was tracking down why my program was getting some unexpected checksum-mismatch errors, in some code that I wrote that serializes and deserializes IEEE-754 floating-point values, in a format that includes a 32-bit checksum value (which is computed by running a CRC-type algorithm over the bytes of the floating-point array).

After a bit of head-scratching, I realized the problem was the 0.0f and -0.0f have different bit-patterns (0x00000000 vs 0x00000080 (little-endian), respectively), but they are considered equivalent by the C++ equality-operator.  So, the checksum-mismatch errors happened because my checksum-calculating algorithm picked up the difference between those two bit-patterns, while certain other parts of my codebase (that use floating point equality testing, rather than looking at the values byte-by-byte) did not make that distinction.

Okay, fair enough -- I should probably have known better than to do floating-point equality testing anyway.

But this got me thinking, are there other IEEE-754 floating point values that are considered equal (according to the C == operator) but have different bit-patterns?  Or, to put it another way, how exactly does the == operator decide whether two floating-point values are equal?  Newbie me though it was doing something like memcmp() on their bit-patterns, but clearly it's more nuanced than that.

Here's a code example of what I mean, in case I wasn't clear above.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void PrintFloatBytes(const char * title, float f)
{
   printf("Byte-representation of [%s] is: ", title);
   const unsigned char * p = (const unsigned char *) &f;
   for (int i=0; i<sizeof(f); i++) printf("%02x ", p[i]);
   printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   const float pzero = -0.0f;
   const float nzero = +0.0f;
   PrintFloatBytes("pzero", pzero);
   PrintFloatBytes("nzero", nzero);
   printf("Is pzero equal to nzero?  %s\n", (pzero==nzero)?"Yes":"No");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/Howto_compare_floating_point_numbers_in_the_C_programming_language FYI, using an epsilon is the way forward for float comparisons. Not on-topic, but useful to know.

Comment: NaNs could go either way (possibly depending on the compiler). They also can be different in memory since there are a large number of possible NaNs (2^24-1 for single precision).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It uses the IEEE-754 equality rules.

- `-0 == +0`
- `NaN != NaN`

Comment: +1 NaN. Note that this is a case where the bit patterns would be the *same*, but `==` would return `false`.

Comment: +1 `NaN`. Also note that you can have different bit patterns representing the two `NaN`s.

Comment: Indeed, +0.0 and -0.0 are the only two distinct bit patterns that can compare equal.

Comment: @Ernest: minor nitpick: `NaN` has a lot of bit patterns.  For 32-bit floats, it would be 2^23 - 1 different bit-patterns.

Answer (score 2):

exact comparison.  That's why it's best to avoid == as a test on floats.  It can lead to unexpected and subtle bugs.

A standard example is this code:

```
 float f = 0.1f;

 if((f*f) == 0.01f)
     printf("0.1 squared is 0.01\n");
 else
     printf("Surprise!\n");
```

because 0.1 can't be represented precisely in binary (it's a repeating whatever the hell you call a fractional binary) `0.1*0.1` won't be exactly `0.01` -- and thus the equality test won't work.

Numerical analysts worry about this at length, but for a first approximation it's useful to define a value -- APL called it FUZZ -- which is how closely two floats need to come to be considered equal.  So you might, for example, `#define FUZZ 0.00001f` and test

```
 float f = 0.1f;

 if(abs((f*f)-0.01f) < FUZZ)
     printf("0.1 squared is 0.01\n");
 else
     printf("Surprise!\n");
```

Comment: Clearly it's not exact comparison on the bit-by-bit level though, or it wouldn't indicate that (-0.0f == 0.0f) because those two values have different bit-patterns.

Comment: A reasonable point that would be more apposite had I written "exact bit by bit comparison".

Answer (score 1):

For Windows platforms, [this link has](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc308050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> - Divide by 0 produces +/- INF, except 0/0 which results in NaN.
> - log of (+/-) 0 produces -INF. log of a negative value (other than -0) produces NaN.
> - Reciprocal square root (rsq) or square root (sqrt) of a negative number produces NaN. The exception is -0; sqrt(-0) produces -0, and rsq(-0) produces -INF.
> - INF - INF = NaN
> - (+/-)INF / (+/-)INF = NaN
> - (+/-)INF * 0 = NaN
> - NaN (any OP) any-value = NaN
> - The comparisons EQ, GT, GE, LT, and LE, when either or both operands is NaN returns FALSE.
> - **Comparisons ignore the sign of 0 (so +0 equals -0).**
> - The comparison NE, when either or both operands is NaN returns TRUE.
> - Comparisons of any non-NaN value against +/- INF return the correct result.